# Gloom as a verb, is it possible?

Tags: word-usage

let’s suppose I’m sad about something.

Can I say “I’m glooming at it”, “I’m glooming at the fact you failed in the exam”?

Comment: Yes, "gloom" is used as a verb. "gloom over" sounds better, though.

Comment: Yes, Oxford Languages gives the verb definition, "be or look depressed or despondent".

Comment: So it works when I say “I’m glooming over it” and it basically means I’m sad about it.

Comment: Odd, though. And potential confusion with glom onto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Gloom’ does exist as a verb, both as a transitive and an intransitive.

According to OED,

‘gloom’ intransitive - “To look sullen or displeased; to frown, scowl, lower; also  to gloom on or  to gloom at (a person); in recent use also (through influence of gloomy, adj.): To look dismal or dejected, to wear an air of sombre melancholy; to be gloomy; of the weather, the sky, etc.: To lower, look dark or threatening; to be or to become dull and cloudy;  To have a dark or sombre appearance; to appear as a dark object.”

1968    H. Franklin Crash vi. 77   I sat and gloomed in the hotel lounge.

1863    T. Woolner My Beautiful Lady  iii. 135   Long toil-devoted years have gloomed and shone Since these events closed up my doors of life.

1850    E. B. Browning Sonnets from Portuguese xix, in  Poems (new ed.) II. 456   The dim purpureal tresses gloomed athwart The nine white Muse-brows.

‘gloom’ transitive - To make dark or sombre; to cover with gloom;

1851    E. B. Browning Casa Guidi Windows  i. xxv. 65   One temple, with its floors Of shining jasper, gloom'd at morn and eve By countless knees of earnest auditors.

1873    Symonds in  Biog. (1895) II. 83   The boredom of this delay at Trapani has, I dare say, gloomed my views of the outer world.

PS **Some of observations on the use of Gloom in literary works:**

*'Gloom' and 'gloomed' in the novels of Charles Dickens*

'Gloom' occurs approximately 150 times, for the most part as a noun, and very occasionally as an adjective. (https://quotations.ch/quotations/#authors=Dickens&words=gloom)

'Gloomed' ('gloom', past tense) appeared twice:

Little Dorrit W Dickens, Charles 1856

> He kissed Amy as she started up to meet him, nodded to Fanny, nodded
> to his father, **gloomed** on the visitor without further recognition,
> and sat down.

Little Dorrit W Dickens, Charles 1856

> At this remark the face of Mr Dorrit **gloomed** considerably. He was
> about (connecting the accrediting with an obtrusive person of the name
> of Clennam, whom he imperfectly remembered in some former state of
> existence) to black-ball the name of Gowan finally, when Edward
> Dorrit, Esquire, came into the conversation, with his glass in his
> eye, and the preliminary remark of ‘I say--you there! Go out, will
> you!’--which was addressed to a couple of men who were handing the
> dishes round, as a courteous intimation that their services could be
> temporarily dispensed with.

For the full list of the occurrences of 'gloom', see
https://quotations.ch/quotations/#authors=Dickens&words=gloom